# How can i locate the Publish link of "orthoacapulco_30cm_cut ? Selenium webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[Publish link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Xkt.jpg)

this is the HTML code

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="id71" class="even">
  <!-- The select row checkbox -->
  <!-- This is a repeater, will generate one td for each property -->
  <td>
    <span></span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span>orthoacapulco_30cm_cut</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span>
      <a id="id64" href="javascript:;"><span>Publish</span></a>
    </span>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I tried everything. By `XPath`, `CSS` selector, by partialLinkName. I can´t use By.ID because never is the same id, and there may be more elements in the table.

Comment: Could you show a few examples of what you tried?  Without more context, providing an answer that is both reliable and concise is difficult.  I'm guessing that you're trying to target the <a> tag specifically within that snippet of code?

Comment: Additionally, you say the id changes with each page refresh.  May more than one instance of this block of code be present or visible on the page at the same time?  That affects the required answer.

Comment: What if there are multiple results on that page? Are you always trying to click the Publish link of the first result? Or the Publish link of "orthoacapulco_30cm_cut"? Or any Publish link?

Comment: Well, I need to locate the publish element of orthoacapulco_30cm_cut, i tried with:

Comment: WebElement publish = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Publish"));
publish.click(); in other cases work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is single link then you can use simply like this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//span[contains(text(),'Publish')]”)).click();
```

It is answer as per your Image, if there are any thing change or there are multiple elements then let me know

Comment: hi,i used your answer but i recived that  Unable to locate element: //span[contains(text(),'Publish')], the id always change and can be multiple elements

Comment: Ok Will try again

Comment: i can solve my problem using this:                
    System.out.println("\n\nSelect Item:");
    List<WebElement> allElement= 
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,\"Publish\")]"));
    int count=allElement.size();
    allElement.get(count-1).click(); thank´s for your help;

Comment: Glad it helps u

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can try this one :

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(“.//tbody//tr[3]”)).get(0).click();
```

Comment: hello , I used your answer and didn´t work  :   Unable to locate element: .//tbody//tr[3]  i can´t finish my test whitout locate this element.